# Passing set of lines in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

In Apache Spark, how can we pass a set of lines (instead of line by line) to transformation function? I am using python.

In my dataset, a set of lines are dependent so i need to process it at same time in a function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely familiar with the python API, in Scala you would do it like this:

```
sc.textFile("/path/blar/blar", numPartitions).mapPartitions(linesIterator => {
  // Some code that uses the lines iterator
})
```

`numPartitions` will influence how many chunks of lines there will be in total and therefore how large the lineIterator will be (Note it's an iterator, so it's lazy - you can avoid OOMs with good code).  I suggest reading the code for the `repartition` method on RDDs to learn more about how partitioning works.

Now doing it this way, there is no easy general O(N) way to ensure the dependent lines are in the same chunk; if you know the dependent lines are in the same file, then don't change the partitions and they will be together.

Without knowing more about the structure and relationships in your data, the only general way I can propose is you map each line to some group number (indexing it's dependent set) then group by that.  E.g.

```
ssc.get.textFile("/path/blar/blar")
.map(line => (someFuncToDecideGroup, line)).groupByKey()
.mapValues(linesSeq => blar blar)
```

Note this time lines is a sequence and so can easily cause memory problems when large, consider coding in a way to utilize `reduceByKey` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use some global variable to store the details like number of lines or any which helps you to group the lines, if you are not able to pass a group of lines (it is not an ideal solution).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this not possible with the Python API for Spark. The SparkContext of the Scala and Java API have a method called `hadoopFile` which takes a custom `InputFormat`, but the Python API seems to lack this feature.
The only way which I see to modify the behavior of RDD creation is to use the method `parallelize` and write your own parser for your files. Of course this is probably not very scalable and could become problematic as the size of your files grows, but it should be sufficient as a quick workaround.
Best, Artjom

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 solutions:

- Use Java or Scala which supports custom `InputFormat`s.
- Pre-process your files to put the dependent lines in a single line each Use another delimiter character to replace newlines. Then you can `split` using that character to get your lines back while processing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since I have been coded the whole project in python, it is not scalable to change the language. My file size is more than 50GB. So splitting it is also not scalable.